# Best way to initialize initial connection with a server for REST calls?

Tags: ajax, rest, connection, database-connection

I've been building some apps that connect to a SQL backend. I use ajax calls to hit WebMethods, a WebAPI, etc.

I notice that the first initial call to the SQL backend retrieves the data fairly slow. I can only assume that this is because it must first negotiate credentials first before retrieving the data. It probably caches this somewhere, and thus, any calls made afterwards come back very fast.

I'm wondering if there's an ideal, or optimal way, to initialize this connection.

My thought was to make a simple GET call right when the page loads (grabbing something very small, like a single entry). I probably wouldn't be using the returned data in any useful way, other than to ensure that any calls afterwards come back faster.

Is this an okay way to approach fixing the initial delay? I'd love to hear how others handle this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that your first call could be slower than subsequent ones

- Depending on your server platform, code may be compiled when first executed
- You may not have an active DB connection in your connection pool
- The database may not have cached indices or data on the first call
- Some VM platforms may take a while to allocate sufficient resources to your server if it has been idle for a while.

One way I deal with those types of issues on the server side is to add startup code to my web service that fetches data likely to be used by many callers when the service first initializes (e.g. lookup tables, user credential tables, etc).

If you only control the client, consider that you may well wish to monitor server health (I use the open source monitoring platform Zabbix.  There are also many commercial web-based monitoring solutions).  Exercising the server outside of end-user code is probably better than making an extra GET call from a page that an end user has loaded.